# How to find missing numbers?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql

I have a table containing a list of numbers. How do I find numbers that are missing from the table?

For instance:

```
numbers   id
 1         1
 5         2
 3         3
 6         4
 7         5
 8         6
 9         7
 20        8
 ....
```

How can I find missing numbers?  Like `4` and there are no numbers between `9` and `20`.

I have tried nothing, but want to know.

Comment: i have tried it in postgresql, below is the result, how to do it in mysql.                                                                                                                                 select s.i as missed from generate_series(1,100) s(i) where s.i not in (select id from employee);

Comment: You should add this as an answer, instead of a comment.

Comment: This question is not well defined: `How can I find missing numbers?` You would need to define more closely *which* numbers are candidates Negative numbers? Only integer numbers? Lower / upper bound? The best answer depends on it. It also depends on the RDBMS yo actually use. Typically, we expect you to declare what you use - except you have reason to need a solution for multiple systems - or a DB-agnostic pure SQL solution?

Comment: Which engine are you using???  The answer varies!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want all missing integer numbers between the minimum and maximum existing id in your table - in a current **Postgres** 9.5 installation like you commented (or at least 9.3):

[@Seb3W already suggested `generate_series()`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/146153/3684). It's more efficient to retrieve min and max in a *single* query, though. It's also preferable to use [set-returning-functions](/questions/tagged/set-returning-functions) like `generate_series()` in the `FROM` list instead of the `SELECT` list (conforming to standard SQL and less error prone).

```
SELECT id
FROM  (SELECT min(id) AS a, max(id) AS z FROM numbers) x, generate_series(a, z) id
LEFT   JOIN numbers n1 USING (id)
WHERE  n1.id IS NULL;
```

Once you have the complete set of candidate numbers, use a run-of-the-mill technique to ...

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

About the `LATERAL` join:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

---

If you don't care about standard SQL and want to squeeze out the last drop of ***performance*** (or in Postgres 9.2 or older without `LATERAL` joins) you *can* use `generate_series()` in the `SELECT` list, but still make it a single `SELECT`:

```
SELECT id
FROM  (SELECT generate_series(min(id), max(id)) FROM numbers) n(id)
LEFT   JOIN numbers n1 USING (id)
WHERE  n1.id IS NULL;
```

If you are after performance, you should have an index on `numbers.id`, of course:

```
CREATE INDEX numbers_id_idx ON numbers (id);
```

Answer (score 2):

In postgresql you can use generate_series :

```
SELECT
  generate_series FROM GENERATE_SERIES(
    (select min(id) from numbers), (select max(id) from numbers)
  ) 
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM numbers WHERE id = generate_series)
```

In mysql your need to generate the serie yourself :
[generate serie mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75785/how-to-generate-a-sequence-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

In sql server,we can use the system table master..spt_values.

```
USE tempdb
GO

create table numbers(id int)
GO

insert into numbers
select 1
insert into numbers
select 1
insert into numbers
select 5
insert into numbers
select 2
insert into numbers
select 3
insert into numbers
select 3
GO

select number from master..spt_values
where type='p' and number <=(select max(id) from numbers)
and number not in (select id from numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL you can do the following:

```
--create a your table
CREATE TABLE ##seq
(id INT IDENTITY (1,1)
, txt VARCHAR(50))

--Build your dataset
INSERT INTO ##seq
        (  txt )
VALUES  ( 'boy'), ('girl'),('parent'),( 'boy'), ('girl'),('parent'),( 'boy'), ('girl'),('parent'),( 'boy'), ('girl'),('parent'),( 'boy'), ('girl'),('parent'),( 'boy'), ('girl'),('parent')

--remove your sequence ids to demonstrate
DELETE FROM ##seq WHERE id IN (2,5,7,8,9)

--Query your sequence for gaps 
SELECT (t1.id + 1) as gap_starts_at, 
       (SELECT MIN(t3.id) -1 FROM ##seq t3 WHERE t3.id > t1.id) as gap_ends_at
FROM ##seq t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.id FROM ##seq t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For MariaDB, it is something like

```
SELECT seq
    FROM seq_1_to_20
    LEFT JOIN tbl AS t  ON t.numbers = seq
    WHERE t.numbers IS NULL
```

[reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/)