# Sum(JSON_EXTRACT) MariaDB 10.3.11

Tags: mariadb, json, sum

I'm looking so long, and cannot find anything right concerning - ho to sum the values from JSON column.

My values in the column looks like this:

```
[{"file":"FILE.doc",
  "POSITION":"3245",
  "NUMBER":"2345",
  "PRICE":"123",
  "PRICE2":"3456",
  "NUMBER":"2019-01-25",
  "date":"2019\/01\/15",
  "added_by":"admin"
 },{
  "file":"FILE.doc",
  "POSITION":"345",
  "numer_faktury":"456",
  "PRICE":"125",
  "PRICE2":"567",
  "DATE":"2019-01-11",
  "DATE":"2019\/01\/15",
  "added_by":"admin"
}]
```

Table = table
column = prices

My select to extract the values looks as follow:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(prices, 
    '$[*].PRICE') as quality FROM table
    WHERE employee_id = 10060
```

And I've got this:

```
|  QUALITY   |
["123", "125"]
```

Is there any possible to sum the values and get:

```
|   QUALITY     |
|   ["248"]     |
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to solve this would be by using [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) which is available since MariaDB 10.2.2. This solution does not need a `numbers` table but recursively iterates the result until the computation of the SUM is complete.

I made a small example which is similar to your data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_json (
    prices JSON NOT NULL,
    employee_id INT
);
INSERT INTO test_json (prices, employee_id) VALUES (
    '[{"PRICE":"123"},{"PRICE":"125"}]', 10060
), (
    '[{"PRICE":"5"},{"PRICE":"10"},{"PRICE":"15"},{"PRICE":"20"}]', 10070
);
```

Now the actual query to retrieve the result:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE json_sum (price_sum, prices) AS (
    -- select all entries you need to calculate the sum for, initialize sum as 0
    SELECT 0 AS price_sum, JSON_EXTRACT(prices, '$[*].PRICE') AS prices FROM `test_json`
    WHERE employee_id = 10060 -- this is your original WHERE condition from your question
  UNION
    SELECT
       -- add the value of the first entry in price array to the sum
       price_sum + JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(json_sum.prices, '$[0]')) AS price_sum,
       -- remove the first entry from the price array, so the next iteration will not add it again
      JSON_REMOVE(json_sum.prices, '$[0]') AS prices
    FROM json_sum
    WHERE JSON_LENGTH(json_sum.prices) > 0
)
-- select all sums, filtering out the rows where calculation is incomplete
SELECT price_sum AS quality FROM json_sum WHERE JSON_LENGTH(json_sum.prices) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Such functions do not exist yet as of MariaDB 10.3, however the basic problem is that SUM() requires a group of rows. By working back from this, we can see that the ideal would be to convert the JSON array `["123", "125"]` into individual rows.

Splitting a comma-separated string into rows has been asked for on Stack Overflow, and discussed in a number of places, but the best description I found [came from Periscope Data](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql).

The only problem I have with this solution is that it requires a *numbers* table with consecutive numbers up to the maximum number of values we will be summing. A number of innovative solutions to that can be found in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql).

Here's what I've come up with, perhaps you can give me some feedback:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS total FROM(
WITH mycte AS (SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(prices))) AS prices_extracted)
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(prices, ',', n), 
    ',', 
    -1
  ))) AS PRICE
FROM mycte
JOIN numbers
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(prices_extracted) 
    - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(prices_extracted, ',', '')) 
    >= n -  1
) derived_table;
```

Comment: Re: the numbers table: Maybe you can use the [MariaDB sequence storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/) to get the numbers. It's also possible to generate numbers on-the-fly with a recursive CTE, see e.g. my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204513/94242).